# How to assign a value from table in database to link <a href></a>?

Tags: php, arrays, class, object

I'm looking how to assign a value from table to a link who is redirecting to the page of the game.

We don't really understand how to do it so that's why I'm asking here.

Our code from TroopManager.php

```
    public function selectTroop(int $id)
{
    $select = $this->pdo->query("SELECT name, strength FROM " . self::TABLE . "WHERE id=:id");
    if ((false == $select) || (false == $select->bindValue(':name', $troop, PDO::PARAM_STR)) || (false == $select->bindValue(':strength', $troop, PDO::PARAM_INT))) {
        return self::ERROR;
    } else {
        if ($select->execute()) {
            $troop = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $troop;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Our code from GameController.php

```
    public function play()
{
    $troops = $this->troopManager->selectAll();
    return $this->twig->render("Game/troop.html.twig", ["troops" => $troops]);
}
```

And where we want to assign it

```
    <div class="container-card">
    <div class="player-card">
        <a href="../../Model/TroopManager.php/selectTroop?click=1">
            <img src="/assets/images/knight.png" class="img-card" alt="archer" name="Knight">
        </a>
```

If you don't want to give the solution can you give a hint please? Because we are really stuck on this right now!

Comment: what error are you getting? the problem is that you arent adding an actual link to the href. just because your file structure is Model/TroopManager.php, does not mean that your actual rewritten path is that too. you will want to redirect to the view which pulls in variable(s) from `$_GET` and build the page / functionality based on that.

Comment: Well we don't really had error, but We want to know how to assign value (int) of a table from database to a link <a href=""> <a> in an html.twig @peterxz